# Good practices and use of DateTime in List of ViewModels

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am making a system for the client, and he did not use fullcalendar, which would be practical. With that, I created in a table with the fields AgendaId (int), and DateAgendar (DateTime) years forward (some 20000 lines).

With that I set up the following ViewModel:

```
public class AgendaAgendamentoVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? AgendamentoId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int? ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string ClienteNome { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a second table called Reserva with the fields:

```
public class Reserva
{
    public int ReservaId { get; set; }
    public int AgendaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string Servico { get; set; }

    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

and Clients:

```
public class Cliente
    {
        public int ClienteId { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        public string Telefone { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        public string Endereco { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

    }
```

The ViewModel code below returns every day from 6 am until 10 pm:

```
IList<AgendaAgendamentoVM> _listaAgendaVM = new List<AgendaAgendamentoVM>();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mes))
    {
        var data = DateTime.Parse(mes);
        ViewBag.Data = data;
        ViewBag.Ontem = data.AddDays(-1);
        ViewBag.Amanha = data.AddDays(1);

        var dias = await _context.Agenda
        .Where(x => x.DataAgenda >= data.AddHours(6))
        .Where(x => x.DataAgenda <= data.AddHours(22))
        .ToListAsync();


        foreach (var item in dias)
        {
            AgendaAgendamentoVM li = new AgendaAgendamentoVM();
            li.Id = item.AgendaId;
            li.Date = DateTime.Parse(item.DataAgenda.ToString());
            _listaAgendaVM.Add(li);
        }

        ViewData["ListaAgenda"] = _listaAgendaVM;
        return View();
```

The View:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Agenda";
}

<form>
<input type="date" name="mes" required /> <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
<div class="row m-1 p-2 bg-success rounded">

<div class="col-4">
<a class="text-white" href="/Agenda/Index?mes=@String.Format("{0:d}", ViewBag.Ontem)"><</a>
</div>

<div class="col-4 text-center text-white font-weight-bolder">
@String.Format("{0:d}", ViewBag.Data)
</div>


<div class="col-4 text-right">
<a class="text-white" href="/Agenda/Index?mes=@String.Format("{0:d}", ViewBag.Amanha)">></a>
</div></div>

<ul class="list-group m-1">
@foreach (var item in ViewData["ListaAgenda"] as 
List<Camarim.Core.ViewModels.AgendaAgendamentoVM>)
{
<li class="list-group-item"><a href="#?agendaid=@item.Id">@String.Format("{0:HH:mm}", 
item.Date) - @item.ClienteNome</a></li>

}
```

Only with the Agenda table, I can display in a view a "navigable" calendar as shown in the image:
[image]

Still in the Reservation table, I have a ClienteId field, where I return a specific customer. In the List I make of the ViewModel, I use a foreach calling the Reservation and Customers table, as shown in the photo:
[image]

The problem with this is, when doing this, the view stops showing the entire list from 6 am to 10 pm, it only shows the fields where clients are scheduled. My goal was to leave it at least this way:
[image: Goal I want to achieve]

How can I do to achieve this goal: and / OR another: Is there any other way to do this without using the database for popular dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to display the `ClientNome`.

Firstly,from your expected result image,it should be one-to-many relationship between `Agenda` and `Reserva`.Then you could get the multiple `ClientNome` to display it in your razor view.Change your model like below:

```
public class Agenda
{
    public int AgendaId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataAgenda { get; set; }
    public List<Reserva> Reserva { get; set; }
}
public class Reserva
{
    public int ReservaId { get; set; }
    public int AgendaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string Servico { get; set; }

    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
public class Cliente
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
}
public class AgendaAgendamentoVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? AgendamentoId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int? ClienteId { get; set; }
    public List<string> ClienteNome { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
    <form>
    <input type="date" name="mes" required /> <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
<div class="row m-1 p-2 bg-success rounded">

    <div class="col-4">
        <a class="text-white" href="/Agenda/Index?mes=@String.Format("{0:d}", ViewBag.Ontem)"><</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 text-center text-white font-weight-bolder">
        @String.Format("{0:d}", ViewBag.Data)
    </div>


    <div class="col-4 text-right">
        <a class="text-white" href="/Agenda/Index?mes=@String.Format("{0:d}", ViewBag.Amanha)">></a>
    </div>
</div>

<ul class="list-group m-1">
    @foreach (var item in ViewData["ListaAgenda"] as List<AgendaAgendamentoVM>)
    {
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <a href="#?agendaid=@item.Id">
                @String.Format("{0:HH:mm}",
                item.Date) - @foreach (var i in item.ClienteNome)
                {
                    @i @string.Format("  ")       @*change this*@
                }
            </a>
        </li>

    }
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string mes)
{
    IList<AgendaAgendamentoVM> _listaAgendaVM = new List<AgendaAgendamentoVM>();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mes))
    {
        var data = DateTime.Parse(mes);
        ViewBag.Data = data;
        ViewBag.Ontem = data.AddDays(-1);
        ViewBag.Amanha = data.AddDays(1);

        var dias = await _context.Agenda
        .Where(x => x.DataAgenda >= data.AddHours(6))
        .Where(x => x.DataAgenda <= data.AddHours(22))
        .ToListAsync();


        foreach (var item in dias)
        {
            var reservas = (from p in _context.Reservas
                            join c in _context.Clientes on p.ClienteId equals c.ClienteId
                            where p.AgendaId == item.AgendaId
                            select c).ToList();
            AgendaAgendamentoVM li = new AgendaAgendamentoVM();
            li.Id = item.AgendaId;
            li.Date = DateTime.Parse(item.DataAgenda.ToString());
            li.ClienteNome = reservas.Select(a => a.Nome).ToList();
            _listaAgendaVM.Add(li);
        }

        ViewData["ListaAgenda"] = _listaAgendaVM;
        return View();
    }
    return View();
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, your answer greatly clarified my understanding. From now, All I had to do is use a <List> to return the one-to-many in case like this